# Some of Font Awesome's icons are not working and some appears as an empty square

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I'm using a Font Awesome CDN in my project on Codepen and when i used the icons tags in my  Html page the icons didn't work at all in the first and when i tried to change the first class `<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>` which is the "fab"  and put "fa" instead like this `<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>` some icons did work but still some doesn't work and some appears as an empty square ! any suggestions?

Comment: some version of icons are PRO so they aren't available in the free package. We need to see which icons your are using to confirm if it's the case

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's the icon i'm using <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/icons/smile?style=solid --> only `far` and `fas` is available for this one and it's not a Brand icon so there is no `fab`. Each icon has a page you need to check to see how to use it and if it's available or not

Comment: @TemaniAfif sure the that's worked with me is <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> after i changed the "fab" with "fa" and the other one <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>  is the one i'm trying to use and did the same with it changed the 'fas' to 'fa' but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your version of fontawsome.
this when your version is not support

Comment: you are right the problem is solved when i used version 4 icons in this page [https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#name-changes], i found that i'm using version 4.7 while Font Awesome icons page is for version 5, even though i got the CDN recently after version 5 is released and that what confused me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this CDN link to call all the CSS scripts for all the fontawesome variants

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />`

Or more still visit this page to make your preferred selection.
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome